# Проблема с vk_api

Tags: python-3.x, vkontakte-api, библиотеки

Вот бот, который должен отправлять несколько сообщений в ответ на одно :

```py
import time
import vk_api
from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll, VkBotEventType

vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token="тут был токен")

longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(vk_session, тут был id группы)
vk = vk_session.get_api()
print("Бот запущен")


def textFromMessages(resolve):
    text = resolve[resolve.find(']') + 2:]
    return text


# Основной цикл
while True:
    time.sleep(5)
    for event in longpoll.listen():
        if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
            if textFromMessages(event.object['text']) == '1':
                if event.from_chat:
                    i = 0
                    while i < 5:
                        vk.messages.send(chat_id=event.chat_id, message='Бунд', random_id=1)
                        i = i+1
                        time.sleep(1)
```

но после отправки первого сообщения он выдаёт ошибку :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vlabey/PycharmProjects/FludBot/main.py", line 26, in <module>
    vk.messages.send(chat_id=event.chat_id, message='Бунд', random_id=1)
  File "/home/vlabey/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/vk_api/vk_api.py", line 671, in __call__
    return self._vk.method(self._method, kwargs)
  File "/home/vlabey/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/vk_api/vk_api.py", line 636, in method
    raise error
vk_api.exceptions.ApiError: [10] Internal server error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы передаёте один и тот же `random_id`.

Этот параметр был создан для отличия сообщений и предотвращения повторной отправки.

Вам следует генерировать его случайным образом, вот пример:

```py
from random import randint


...
vk.messages.send(chat_id=event.chat_id, message='Бунд', random_id=randint(1, 2147483647))
...
```